# Vim, mapping non-standard keys (forward/back/zoom in/zoom out/favorites)

Tags: vim, keyboard, neovim

I have a Microsoft Ergonomic 4000 keyboard and want to map some of its non standard(pc102) keyboard keys in Vim/NeoVim.

for example I wish to map the "Forward", "Back" keys and "zoom in", "zoom out" keys

I use Linux(Ubuntu) and can change the keyboards keys assignments using udev creating a new rule based on  /lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb
In my searching I found the following below.

Keyboard **scancodes** tested via, sudo scankey -s

```
 e066 - Favorites
 e069 - Forward
 e06a - Back
 e048 - Zoom/Up
 e050 - Zoom/Down
```

Keyboard ***functions***, I could use for remapping in udev, https://hal.freedesktop.org/quirk/quirk-keymap-list.txt

```
    scrollup/scrolldown
    zoomin/zoomout
    forward/back
    favorites
```

X86/X11 ***Keysym***, if that's useful https://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/XF86_keyboard_symbols

```
    XF86Favorites
    XF86Back
    XF86Forward
    XF86Launch0 thru 9
    XF86ScrollUp
    XF86ScrollDown
```

but I don't know how to take the next step and map them in vim.  I can't find a key-notation that match these keys/functions so I don't know how to do the following for example

```
" psuedo config for maping 'Zoom In' key to 'Page Up'
remap <ZoomIn> <PageUp>
```

Some sites I've found but couldn't figure it out.

- https://7id.xray.aps.anl.gov/software/vim/intro.html#notation
- http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#key-notation
- http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/term.html

Any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Not my favorite idea, but as a start, what happens if you map one of these weird keys to a standard key, then map the standard key to whatever you want? If you could make the `Forward` button, for example, execute some key combo you never use like `ctrl + F6`, then you could map `ctrl + F6` in your `.vimrc` to whatever you wanted.

Comment: not ideal, as I would loose functionality in other programs, unless i map all programs to accept these.  But unless there is a better idea, this is what i will do.

Comment: IMHO when using VI-like editors, learn the native keys and use those; maybe VI(m) is just not the best editor to use. About 30 years ago I ported MicroEMACS to the PC (16 bit at that time), and I was happy with the keyboard mappings possible. But with 32-bit I switched to the real Emacs (19 at that time). I'm still using Emacs a lot, and VI(M) occasionally.

Answer (score 2):

You can see if those keys somehow produce recognisable escape sequences by following this method:

1. Open Vim.
2. Enter insert mode.
3. Press `<C-v>`, then the key you want to test.
4. Use what is inserted directly in your mapping, for example:

   ```
   nnoremap ^[OH <do something>
   ```

If they don't, you could use a utility to make them output something usable and then use that something in your mapping. It could be a custom escape sequence or a unicode character like `™`, which you could use like so:

```
nnoremap ™ <do something>
```

Comment: Tried with Forward key(keycode 167, keysym XF86Forward), nothing showed up. same for the others